# Is the zero map an endomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Context: I managed to prove that if $\phi$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $$\langle{v, w}\rangle':=\langle\phi(v), \phi(w)\rangle\quad(\forall v, w \in \mathbb{R}^n)$$ is an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n.$

The question I have is if this would still hold if $\phi$ was only an endomorphism?

It seems to me that the criterion $\langle{v, v}\rangle'>0, \forall v\neq0$ would fail, since $\phi = 0$ is an endomorphism, isn't it?

Comment: this is false, as the kernel of an arbitrary endomorphism is not necessarily trivial

Comment: If $\phi$ was not bijective, you would have $\langle v,v \rangle' = 0$ for any $v \in \mathrm{ker} (\phi)$, so in particular for non-zero vectors.

Comment: You rightly gave a counterexample in you last sentence. So, what is your question?

Comment: I have little confidence in correctly understanding endomorphisms. I was not sure if $f: x \mapsto 0x$ was a valid endomorphism in this example.

Comment: If so, your question should rather be: "Is $x\mapsto0$ an endomorphism of $\Bbb R^n?$" or "Is the zero map (between two given vector spaces) linear?" This would save everybody's time.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, I'm kind of new to this forum so what would be the correct way to edit my question. Shortening it to what you just said feels like a bit of a waste and makes the above comments seem random. Is it more appropriate to leave the example of the automorphism and just edit the question at the end?

Comment: I shall give you my opinion by editing your post myself. Please feel free to rollback if you do not fully agree.